# Ubuntu 16.04 sound

Tags: sound

the "Line" input doesn't work from an external sound source but the onboard sound does work for online content and recorded CD/DVDs.  The alsamixer shows that the "Line" is muted, how does one get it unmuted to the "OO state so it will work?  The "line" input might not be recognized by the system since the upgrade to 16.04---it shows in the Bios that the onboard sound is turned on?
Help!  It did work OK in version 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Run `alsamixer` hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to show all, then cursor over to the  Muted line input (likely labled CAPTURE) with the red text and hit M to unmute then cursor up to the desired level. See below for a related but not exact example.

[image]